# Value in array not not assigned - java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, assign

My 2D array is not being assigned values as it should.
The method is called here:

```
public static void inputPair() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Enter symbol which you want to pair letter to:");
    char s = 'a';
    while (s == 'a') {
        try {
            s = input.next(".").charAt(0);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid symbol!");
            input.next();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Enter letter which you want to pair symbol to:");
    char l = '#';
    while (l == '#') {
        try {
            l = input.next(".").charAt(0);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid letter!");
            input.next();
        }
        if ((s <= 'a') && (s >= 'z')) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid letter!");
            l = '#';
        }
    }
    makePair(s, l);
    System.out.println("Pair made!");
}
```

and the makePair method:

```
public static void makePair(char s, char l) {
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        words[i] = words[i].replace(s, l);
    }
    try {
        pairings[findFree()][0] = Character.toString(l);
        pairings[findFree()][1] = Character.toString(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please start again!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This should assign the value of l and s into the 2D array at the first empty cell due to the findFree method:

```
public static int findFree() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pairings.length; i++) {
        if (pairings[i][0] == null) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 27; // Greater than 26
}
```

However the cell remains having the value of null.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you set break points and stepped through the code with a debugger, looking at what is actually going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the only problem, but it seems wrong:

```
pairings[findFree()][0] = Character.toString(l);
pairings[findFree()][1] = Character.toString(s);
```

1. `findFree()` will find index of an array in the `pairings` 2D array whose value at index 0 is `null`, let's say it's 0.
2. Value of `l` will be assigned to `[0][0]`
3. You call `findFree()` **again** - `pairings[0]` will not be selected, because it already contains `l` (which is not null) at index 0, so the next one will be selected (let's say 1)
4. Value of `l` will be assigned to `[1][1]`.

Thus you will end up with `[l][null]` and `[null][s]`, instead of the desired `[l][s]` (at least I assume that this is the result you want).

To fix it do something like this:

```
int freeIndex = findFree();
pairings[freeIndex][0] = Character.toString(l);
pairings[freeIndex][1] = Character.toString(s);
```